# Joining elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like:

```
data = [('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2')]
```

And I want to generate a string like this: `"('a1', 'a2'), ('b1'. 'b2')"`

If i do something like: `','.join(data)`, I get an error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

If I want to do something in a single line without doing something like:

```
for elem in data:
  str += ',%s' % str(elem)
```

then is there a way?

Comment: and why do you want to have such an output?

Answer (score 14):

Use a generator to cast the tuples to strings and then use `join()`.

```
>>> ', '.join(str(d) for d in data)
"('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Discard the opening and closing brackets from `str()` output:

```
>>> data = [('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2')]
>>> str(data)
"[('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2')]"
>>> str(data)[1:-1]
"('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2')"
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
','.join(str(i) for i in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers by payne and marcog are correct, as they directly convert the tuple to a string.

If you need more flexibility with the output format, you can unpack the tuple inside the generator expression and use its values as parameters to a format string in this way:

```
    ", ".join("first element: %s, second element: %s" % (str(x), str(y)) for x, y in data)
```

In this way you can overcome the default `str` representation of a tuple.

Comment: you don't need explicitly convert to str elements of tuple: 1. they're already strings, 2. they will be implicitly converted when formatting string.