# numbers in a list (python)

Tags: python, list, count

Is it possible to put numbers toghether from a list?

```
>>> ['A', '3', '4']
['A', '34']

>>> ['3', 'A', '4']
['A', '34']

>>> ['A', '4', '3']
['A', '43']
```

I tried to make strings but I never know how much numbers there are... otherwiste I could do:

```
>>>'3' + '4'
'34'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874514/joining-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string` method `isdigit` to see if a string is composed only of numbers. So basically you can collect all the non-numbers in a list, then `join` all the numbers and add them as a single element.

```
>>> l = ['A', '3', '4', 'B', '6']
>>> [i for i in l if not i.isdigit()] + [''.join(i for i in l if i.isdigit())]
['A', 'B', '346']
```