# 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1select f.name

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am getting this error in django when I am trying hit mysql database. but when I ran this query in db I got proper result my query is like

```
"select f.name,scheduleDepart.depart_time,scheduleArrive.arrival_time,ai.name from 
                flight as f,airline as ai,flight_schedule as scheduleDepart inner join  
                flight_schedule as scheduleArrive on scheduleDepart.flight_id=scheduleArrive.flight_id
                where scheduleArrive.location_id=%d and scheduleDepart.location_id=%d
                 and scheduleArrive.flight_id=f.id and f.airline_code_id=ai.id;""".join(''.join(elems) for elems in data)
```

this is my stack trace

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\kepsla-workspace\WS\demoWS\flightBooking\booking\views.py", line 30, in flightBooking
    and scheduleArrive.flight_id=f.id and f.airline_code_id=ai.id;""".join(''.join(elems) for elems in data))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1select f.name,scheduleDepart.depart_time,scheduleArrive.arrival_time,ai.name fr' at line 1")
[06/Jul/2017 23:28:28] "POST /booking HTTP/1.1" 500 162085
```

any help???
here is python file of view it doesn't have anywhere 1

```
def flightBooking(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form= SearchForm(request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
          return render(request, 'booking/search.html',{'form':form})
        else:
                form.is_valid()
                data=( form.cleaned_data['fromLocation'],form.cleaned_data['toLocation'])
                cursor=connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("""select f.name,scheduleDepart.depart_time,scheduleArrive.arrival_time,ai.name from 
                flight as f,airline as ai,flight_schedule as scheduleDepart inner join  
                flight_schedule as scheduleArrive on scheduleDepart.flight_id=scheduleArrive.flight_id
                where scheduleArrive.location_id=%d and scheduleDepart.location_id=%d
                 and scheduleArrive.flight_id=f.id and f.airline_code_id=ai.id;""".join(''.join(elems) for elems in data))
                results=dictFetchAll(cursor)
                return render(results,'booking/searchResult.html')
                #return HttpResponse(results,'booking/searchResult.html')

    def dictFetchAll(cursor):
        "return all rows with column name"
        columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description]
        return [
                dict(zip(columns,row))
                for row in cursor.fetchall()
            ]
```

EDIT 2:
here is my query after joining datainside date validation

```
1select f.name,scheduleDepart.depart_time,scheduleArrive.arrival_time,ai.name from 
                flight as f,airline as ai,flight_schedule as scheduleDepart inner join  
                flight_schedule as scheduleArrive on scheduleDepart.flight_id=scheduleArrive.flight_id
                where scheduleArrive.location_id=%d and scheduleDepart.location_id=%d
                 and scheduleArrive.flight_id=f.id and f.airline_code_id=ai.id;2
```

Comment: What does your query evaluate to when you deal with `.join(''.join(elems) for elems in data)`? Clearly, it's not behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: am not sure how it appends I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874514/joining-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: @Jacobm001:I can guess it but rather down voting if you help me how to solve it will encourage me

Comment: The error message pretty much sums up the problem. Somewhere "1" is prepended to the SQL statement. Look through the code (we can't because you didn't share it) to see where the SQL statement might be altered.

Comment: I did not down vote your question. Though it's hard for me to guess when I have no idea what `elems` or `data` look like. I don't have the tools to check these things; you do.

Comment: @SloanThrasher: have added full code please see once

Comment: @vihangshah: what does the `.join(...)` bit evaluate to?

Comment: @Jacobm001: I need 2 fields so I added tuple but it was giving me error. so *join* converts that tuple into string

Comment: Why the three quotes around the SQL statement? The statement would then begin and end with quotes (which it shouldn't).

Comment: You might try putting the SQL statement into a variable, then printing it out so you can see exactly what you are passing to the execute function.

Comment: @vihang: Do you not understand the question? What does it evaluate to!? Meaning, if you were to `print()` the out the results of calling that `query.join(..)` bit, what would you see?

Comment: @Jacobm001:oohh sorry I added that I got my problem but I do not know how to solve it..:(

Comment: Where to begin... You're using your SQL statement as a delimiter in a call to `str.join()`, which of course makes no sense. To add to that, pretty much any form of string concatenation or formatting in order to pass values to your query is the wrong way to do it, and potentially insecure. You seem to be reading the data from a web form, so even a slight error on your part will lead to SQL injection. Now, you do actually have placeholders in place in your SQL, though you should be using `%s` always, since SQL placeholders are not Python's format string placeholders...

Comment: @IljaEverilä:can you please how to rectify this? I am from different back ground and just started learning django

Comment: ...You've also formed a sequence, or tuple, of arguments in `data`, though it'd seem it is a sequence of sequences. Were it a 2-tuple of ID integers instead, you'd simply have to `cursor.execute("""select ...""", data)`. Again, **this is not string formatting**. You pass the arguments as a sequence to `execute()`, so that the DB-API driver can then handle all quoting etc. for you and replace the placeholders suitably. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly carefully and observe how arguments are passed to `execute()`.

Comment: @IljaEveriläI tried that way but I got error saying that **str expected,bytes got**

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `repr(data)` in order for people to be able to help you further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148542/discussion-between-vihang-shah-and-ilja-everila).

Answer (score 0):

Django provide a DB based in ORM sytem but if you want continue with raw sql check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/