# Joining elements of a list with a character

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
f=[('soybean', 'vegetable_oil'), ('bay', 'smoke'), ('gelatin', 'watermelon')]
```

I want to join each element such that I get

```
['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']
```

To do that I do the following:

```
list=[]
for i in f:
    s=':'
    list=s.join(f)
    print(list)
```

But thus returns:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

I realised also there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874514/joining-elements-of-a-list) but when I do

```
':'.join(str(d) for d in f)
```

I get:

```
"('soybean', 'vegetable_oil'):('bay', 'smoke'):('gelatin', 'watermelon')"
```

which is not what I am after, I wonder what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You were pretty close! just change this line `list=s.join(f)` to: `list.append(s.join(i))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`':'.join(str(d) for d in f)` does joining on list elements and not on the inner tuples.

Use following list-comprehension:

```
[':'.join(x) for x in f]
```

**Example**:

```
f = [('soybean', 'vegetable_oil'), ('bay', 'smoke'), ('gelatin', 'watermelon')]

print([':'.join(x) for x in f])
# ['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using f-string formatting with list comprehension if using Python 3.6+:

```
[f'{i}:{j}' for i, j in f]
```

Output

```
['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) with [`list.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
list(map(':'.join, f))
# ['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this list comprehension :

```
>>> f=[('soybean', 'vegetable_oil'), ('bay', 'smoke'), ('gelatin', 'watermelon')]
>>> [':'.join(k) for k in f]
['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use for loop on the list, you iterate over each element in the list, which, in this case, are tuples. This means you are looping through the list and not the inner tuples.

Say, you have this list: [(0, 0), (2, 4), (-3, 9)]

When you apply for loop on the list then you get a tuple element each time.

In order to get the required result as mentioned in the question, you could use the following code:

```
for element in my_list:
    my_list.insert(my_list.index(element), ":".join(element))
        my_list.remove(element)
```

Hope this helped you!